# Allocate memory for two dimensional array of integers but it should be continuous

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc

I want to allocate memory to two dimensional array of type `int` but, the memory should be continuous.

it should be freed by just making one call to `free( ptr )`. I should need not to call free to each block of memory.

Comment: Multiply `M * N * sizeof (int)` and do `malloc` for such memory block. M and N are number of elements in each dimension.

Answer (score 5):

Formally, it is done like this:

```
int (*arr_ptr) [x][y] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );

(*arr_ptr)[i][j] = something; // access one element

free(arr_ptr);
```

However, this makes access of the elements a bit inconvenient: `(*arr_ptr)[i][j]` is a bit hard to read. A trick to avoid this, is to leave out one dimension of the array pointer and instead regard it as an array of one-dimensional arrays:

```
int (*arr_ptr) [y] = malloc( sizeof(int[x][y]) );

arr_ptr[i][j] = something; // access one element

free(arr_ptr);
```

If you have an ancient compiler, you must create a more ugly, "mangled" 2D array:

```
int* ptr = malloc( sizeof(int) * x * y );

ptr[i*y + j] = something; // access one element

free(ptr);
```

Comment: Really cool idea using variable length arrays like this. For those who don't know, “ancient compiler” means “pre C99 compiler” such as MSVC.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) then you can write the following way

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    size_t m = 3;
    size_t n = 4;

    int ( *a )[n] = malloc( m * n * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) a[i][j] = i * n + j;
    }        

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }        

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 0  1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7 
 8  9 10 11
```

Otherwise `n` must be a constant. For example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 4

int main( void )
{
    size_t m = 3;

    int ( *a )[N] = malloc( m * N * sizeof( int ) );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) a[i][j] = i * N + j;
    }        

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < m; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < N; j++ ) printf( "%2d ", a[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }        

    free( a );

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use a one dimensional array as a two dimensional one, like in the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 2
#define M 3

/*
   array has N * M elemts:

   |    N    |    N    |    N    |
   v         v         v         v
   |----|----|----|----|----|----|


   array[i][j] == array[i*N + j]
*/

#define GET(i,j) (i*N + j)


int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int *array;
    int i, j;

    array = malloc(N * M *sizeof(int));


    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            array[i*N + j] = i+j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("array[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, array[i*N + j]);

    printf("Using the macro:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            printf("array[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j, array[GET(i,j)]);

    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

I also defined a macro `GET(i,j)` so that the code will be more readable, actually this is really needed only to handle more complex cases then the two dimensional one.